# Resolution for different layers using Python GDAL

Tags: gdal, linux, python-3, centos

I'm extracting data from a GRIB file using GDAL in Python 3 on CentOS.

The model is 40 km resolution, and is usually 151x93.

When I try to extract data from band 195, I get the following error:

> Error 4: 'vsimem/work_grib_0x2a194da.jpc' not recognized as a
>   supported file format.
>
> dec_jpeg2000: Unable to open JPEG2000 image within GRIB file.

Is the JPEG2000 driver available?

> Warning 1: Band 295 of GRIB dataset is 108x94, while the first band
>   and dataset is 151x113. Georeferencing of band 295 may be incorrect,
>   and data access may be incomplete.

Could the resolution warning be coming from using the wrong driver?

When I call band.XSize, it reports 151, rather than 108.

Can this be resolved in Python?

*Edit:* the source for the warning message is found here:

http://even.rouault.free.fr/coverage/frmts/grib/gribdataset.cpp.gcov.html